# Javascript GM_xmlhttpRequest change var

Tags: javascript, variables, global, greasemonkey

I tried to do that :

```
var a = []; // Global array
GM_xmlhttpRequest({
      method: "GET",
      url: 'http://server.com/page.php',
      onload: function (response) {

        a.push(response.responseText);
      }
});

alert(a);
```

But "a" is empty, how can i push into "a" array inside onload function? Thank you in advance.

Comment: you are pushing into array...but you can't read it until the asynchronous request has completed

Comment: Thanks, I solved my problem!